# Accessing text in a .reg file

Tags: cmd, registry

I am having difficulty accessing the text in a registry file I am saving and exporting. I can see all of the text from the file by exporting it onto the desktop.

This is the line I'm using to export the .reg file to the desktop (in CMD):

```
REGEDIT /E  "\\%computername%\c$\users\admin\desktop\userpaths.reg" "HKEY_USERS\TempHive"
```

This is the line that isn't working:

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G in (userpaths.reg) Do IF /I "%%G" equ %end% (GOTO part2) else (@ECHO %%G>>parsed.txt)
```

That second line of code is supposed to copy everything from userpaths.reg until %%G is equal to the first line of code I don't want to copy into parsed.txt . I'm using it to crop everything from that line on.

I have tried much simpler lines of code than this to see the contents of the file, but regardless, I can't see the text from the userpaths.reg file that I'm saving from the command line. It doesn't matter if I use the `COPY` or `RENAME` command and make it into a .txt file either.

The strange thing is that when I make a new text file myself and copy the contents of the userpaths.reg file into the text file, I can use the text file I created without a hitch. What is going on?

Comment: You haven't described what it is you expect that line of batch code to do. Does the `userpaths.reg` file exist? (Use `dir *.reg` from a command prompt in the folder.) A .reg file is indeed plain text, as you can see by opening it using notepad (`notepad.exe userpaths.reg` from a command prompt in the folder it's in), if it exists. Is there actually a `HKEY_USERS\TempHive` entry in the registry? (I don't have one in the registry on my machine.)

Comment: That's information that belongs in your question, not buried in a comment. Please [edit] your question and add it there. :-)

Comment: The /E option for REGEDIT is to export the file userpaths.reg to that place on my desktop. Once that line runs, it does exist, and I can see the five megs of text that compose the registry.

Comment: I also noticed that if I even start a new file after opening and viewing a .reg associated file in word pad, it will have the same inaccessible properties.

Comment: I have no idea what "start a new file" and "inaccessible properties" mean. What "new file", and what is "starting it"? Do you mean "open it"? An exported .reg file is a plain text file; it has no "properties", and therefore can't have any that are "inaccessible". It's **text**. View it in Notepad, and you'll see there is nothing there but plain text. If you want help, you need to be much more specific about what the problem is you're having; I can't make any sense out of what you're saying, and apparently no one else can either.